# How to deploye laravel and vue spa on azure webapp?

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, azure-web-app-service

i have created webapp and uploaded my code using ftp,, then create cd /home/site/ext and install composer and nodenpm on it,, then buld the code using npm run pod and it's compiled succesfully,, i m using spa laravel vue,,,then place the url in my .env and also on snacturm files,   the defalut file look like below in laravel root,,, note i have test the app on share hosting and it's working fine on localhost  as well,

```
server {
    #proxy_cache cache;
        #proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    root /home/site/wwwroot/public; # changed for Laravel
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com; 

    location / {            
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # changed for Laravel
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /html/;
    }
    
    # Disable .git directory
    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout         300; 
        fastcgi_send_timeout           3600; 
        fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }
}
```

htacces in root of laravel

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

but when i visit the site now it show 403 forbiden ,,note it's laravel vue spa ,everything is build inside laravel not seprated,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create a script to copy the nginx default file every time the deploy is performed? I question this because when the pipeline is run, the server is restarted and everything outside the home folder is reset, including the nginx configuration file.

Look this article:  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/configure-nginx-for-php-8-linux-azure-app-service/ba-p/3069373

Comment: Hi, yes i tried everything,, i have the default file insie site. as well,, i have added the public site/wwwroot.public but no luck yet

Comment: Excellent it's working now,, this step should be included in thire laravel app tutorial,,,, can you give me another favour,,,, i have to connet it to sql database remotly,,,, so localy i had to configure sql php drivers,,,, but howbto enbale that or install the driver on azure php ,to start the sql databse connectivity with laravel app

Comment: Hi,,, it's working but when i register a user or any form,,and hit the submit button it's validate the data and return that errors,,, but when the data is correct and i submit it show 404,,